# MySQL: Configure the cascade limit (recursion depth)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) say:

> A self-referential .. ON DELETE CASCADE [is allowed, but] ..
>   Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.

In MySQL 5.7, is this number configurable?

I think [`max_sp_recursion_depth`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_sp_recursion_depth) is only for stored procedures.

Comment: We express a tree structure using a `parent_id` (ie. an Adjacency List) and we want to cascade-delete subtrees with a few dozen levels.

Comment: I think that you are mixing up two separate things - a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship or relationships that extend 15 levels deep and an adjacancy list table - which is only `one level` (i.e. all levels are expressed within the one table) and which can express an arbitrary level of hierarchy levels? [This](https://blog.duncanworthy.me/sql/hierarchical-data-pt1-adjacency-list/) might help.